# parse json nested dictionaries within array

Tags: json, python-3.x

How to convert

```
json_decode = [{"538":["1,2,3","hello world"]},{"361":["0,9,8","x,x,y"]}]
```

to

```
{"538":["1,2,3","hello world"],"361":["0,9,8","x,x,y"]}
```

in python?

Comment: It is not clear what you'd like to achieve. May I suggest you reformulate the problem and add some context?

Comment: so I have multiple dictionaries separated by a comma, in a list. and each key has a value which is in a list. so I need to parse json_decode to this format. how do i do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is guaranteed that json_decode is a `list` of `dictionaries`, you can get your desired output with the following:

```
dict([list(x.items())[0] for x in json_decode])
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you use something like:

```
def merge_dicts(dict1, dict2):
    return dict(list(dict1.items()) + list(dict2.items()))

l = [{"538":["1,2,3","hello world"]},{"361":["0,9,8","x,x,y"]}]   
print merge_dicts(l[0], l[1])
```

Output:

```
{'361': ['0,9,8', 'x,x,y'], '538': ['1,2,3', 'hello world']}
```